# Set background of the selected node in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a horizontal ListView, which shows some items in the form of folders. Clicking on these items opens the childs of that node. I want to set the background of the selected node. I'm able to do this with this code in the Adapter class:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursorPosition = cursor.getPosition();
    if (this.cursorPosition == selectedPosition) {
        holder.title.setBackgroundResource(R.color.toc_selected);
    }
}
```

Here `selectedPosition` is the position of the selected item, I'm setting it at different place.

This code fails in case of swiping the items to the left/right after clicking on the item. At a time the `ListView` shows 8 items with the value of `cursor.getPosition()` as `0,1,2,...,7`. If we swipe the `ListView` the 9th element will have value of `cursor.getPosition()` as 0 and element 10th has value 1 and so on. So if we select the first node then it will select the 1st as well as 9th node in the list view. The position is updated in case of swiping the View. Also if we select the 9th item then the 1st item will also be get selected because the getPosition of 1st and 9th node are same i.e. 0.

Is there any way to get out of this situation?

Comment: post detailed code of the horizontal list view

Comment: @user603125 that code is very big(400 lines), cant post here